# How to show the first true element after if condition in for loop in django template?

Tags: django, for-loop, django-templates

I have a for loop in Django template. After that, I check for coincidences. But in some cases, there are might be 3 coincidences. I need to show only the first coincidence. Now, my code returns the name for 3 times, because, there are 3 coincidences

```
{% for ip in ips %}
   {% if d.name == ip.name %}
        <strong>{{ d.name}} </strong>                               
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

**SOLUTION**
It is impossible to break forloop in django template, so I decided to change in views.py through queryset distinction of similar names

```
ips = Point.objects.defer('point').order_by('name').distinct('name')
```

Comment: Please share your models, this does *not* belong in the template, since it is business logic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't recommend doing this in Django Template , but in views itself. But if you can't then you can use `{{ forloop|break }}`.

Something like this :

```
{% for ip in ips %}
   {% if d.name == ip.name %}
        {{ forloop|break }}
        <strong>{{ d.name}} </strong>                               
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Check the small snippet example [here](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2093/)...

Comment: Thank you, I decided to change in views.py through queryset distinction of similar names